# Is the size of inodes fixed?

Tags: linux, filesystems, inode

We divide files into fixed-sized blocks and store it.

I want to know whether the size of an inode for a file is the same size as the block or is it different and has some fixed size?

Comment: It depends upon the file system. Read [Ext2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext2) wikipage and look at its picture

Comment: I read in wiki page that in ext2 system, we divide the entire disk space into blocks and allocate them. So in this file system will inode will occupy a single block or multiple blocks ? Are there file systems where block size and inode size are different?

Answer (score 7):

A block contains a a file's actual data, so typically we want the block to be as large as possible, while still having decent performance. It turns out that a pretty good size for a block is about the size of a page. To cite [the ext4 wiki](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Blocks):

> Block size is specified at mkfs time and typically is 4KiB. You may
>   experience mounting problems if block size is greater than page size
>   (i.e. 64KiB blocks on a i386 which only has 4KiB memory pages).

The "mkfs time" refers to the time at which the file system is created. So the block size is fixed once we have created the file system, and will be 4KiB, most likely.

The inodes only need to contain pointers to the data blocks (and also some meta information about the file - what time it was last accessed, which user it belongs to etc.). In a [different section](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Inode_Size) of the wiki, they state that

> By default, ext4 inode records are 256 bytes, and (as of October 2013)
>   the inode structure is 156 bytes [...]. The extra space
>   between the end of the inode structure and the end of the inode record
>   can be used to store extended attributes. Each inode record can be as
>   large as the filesystem block size, though this is not terribly
>   efficient.

So we *could* indeed make the inodes as large as the blocks, but in a real system this is probably not the case. In case you're wondering, the inode *structure* talks only about the pointers to the data blocks. So we have 156 bytes of pointers to the actual file contents, but the whole inode takes up 256 bytes - basically, we have 100 bytes we can use at our leisure, for whatever metadata we desire.

In short, ext4 is very configurable. But chances are very high that your block size is 4KiB, while your inode records are 256 bytes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a doubt about ext2 system. In ext2 system, entire disk space is divided into blocks so even inode has to occupy a single block. What is inode space is small and block size is large , will the space be wasted ? Also what if inode size is larger than block size, will inode span across 2 or more blocks ?